# KDE Plasma 5 - reload kdeglobals or set default browser via command line

Tags: linux, debian, kde, kde-plasma-5

What is the correct command to reload the KDE global desktop settings file? Or more specifically, how to reset the system default browser via command line?

I am on the latest debian 10 with KDE Plasma 5.14.5. I have the following snippet which used to work and auto-apply immediately.

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kdeglobals --group General --key BrowserApplication "chromium.desktop"
# or "firefox-exr.desktop"
```

But recently it somehow ceased to auto-apply. I have tried the following workarounds to trigger reload of the KDE config, but with no luck.

```
$ dbus-send --type=signal --dest=org.kde.KWin /KWin reloadConfig                                                                                    
Must use org.mydomain.Interface.Signal notation, no dot in "reloadConfig"
FAIL: 1

$ qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure                                                                                                              
# (no error message returned but did not work)
```

Additional system info:

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.54.0
Qt Version: 5.11.3
Linux Kernel Version: 4.19.0-16-amd64
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but as far as I know, you must not use the full path but just the name of the file inside `.confg`. Thus, in your example it should be
`kwriteconfig5 --file kdeglobals ...` I don't know if that's the cause of your problem though

Comment: No, that is unrelated. Both ways can edit the `kdeglobals` file but won't apply the change.

Comment: You're right, it works for writing, it does not work for reading if you specify the full path, and that's unrelated I agree

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I just gave up.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an actual *solution* to this, but I do have a workaround that might work instead (depending on what the exact goal is): add another layer of indirection.

In my case, I want to switch the default browser depending on what activity I'm in, so I used to have a service that monitored activity changes and set the default browser as appropriate. Instead, I now have a wrapper script that is set as the default browser, and calls the correct real browser when it's run, like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function currentActivityName() {
    local service=org.kde.ActivityManager
    local path=/ActivityManager/Activities
    qdbus $service $path ActivityName "$(qdbus $service $path CurrentActivity)"
}

case "$(currentActivityName)" in
    Work)
        exec google-chrome --new-window "$@"
        ;;
    *)
        exec vivaldi-stable --new-window "$@"
        ;;
esac
```

So if your criteria are easy to check like this, a similar approach might be the easiest path.

(Given how long it's been, I imagine the OP no longer needs this, but this question ranked highly on Google when I was trying to find out if anyone else has solved this problem.)

Comment: Thanks for such an awesome workaround. I will try this activity-based strategy and see whether it suits my use cases. An actual solution, however, would be still more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to change the default browser in kde plasma with command line by adding mime type modifications:

```bash
      db="Firefox Developper Edition.desktop"
      kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kdeglobals --group General --key BrowserApplication $db
      xdg-settings set default-web-browser $db
      xdg-mime default "$db" x-scheme-handler/https
      xdg-mime default "$db" x-scheme-handler/http
```

---

My personnal use case is : change default browser when i switch activities. To do this, we must create folders in `~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/activities/` corresponding to the activity ids: the scripts contained in these will run automatically when activities change. To know the name/id of the activities:

```bash
qdbus --literal org.kde.ActivityManager /ActivityManager/Activities ListActivitiesWithInformation
# exemple output →
#[Argument: a(ssssi) {[Argument: (ssssi) "25414bcd-3e75-4b9e-93fd-d32702b1043d", "dev", "", "format-text-code", 2], [Argument: (ssssi) "958d1270-b221-4d5e-aed1-4f9f38260a7c", "Défaut", "", "", 2]}]
```

Creation of folders for executing scripts during activity changes (adapt id) →

```bash
mkdir -r ~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/activities/25414bcd-3e75-4b9e-93fd-d32702b1043d/activated/
```

I put here the script which should be executed when this activity is loaded:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function writeconf() {
      db="Firefox Developper Edition.desktop"
      kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kdeglobals --group General --key BrowserApplication $db
      xdg-settings set default-web-browser $db
      xdg-mime default "$db" x-scheme-handler/https
      xdg-mime default "$db" x-scheme-handler/http
      # xdg-mime default "$db" text/html
}

writeconf 
kdialog --title "workspace: dev" --passivepopup "Browser is now to Firefox Developer Edition"
```

I do the same thing for loading the default activity, to revert the browser to default.
More information on managing scripts launched during activity changes [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/rqvgr2/run_custom_scripts_when_launching_activities/)